# javafx exception when get image from metadata

Tags: java, javafx

When i try to get an image from mp3, i catch an exception.

```
public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
public Media media;
public MediaView mediaView;
public ImageView albumPicture;

public void initialize() {
    media = new Media(new File("res\\music.mp3").toURI().toString());
    media.getMetadata().addListener(new MapChangeListener<String, Object>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Change<? extends String, ?> c) {
            if (c.wasAdded()) {
                if ("image".equals(c.getKey())) {
                    albumPicture.setImage((Image)c.getValueAdded());
                }
            }
        }
    });

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
```

Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sample.Controller$1.onChanged(Controller.java:67)
        at com.sun.javafx.collections.MapListenerHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(MapListenerHelper.java:163)
        at com.sun.javafx.collections.MapListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(MapListenerHelper.java:72)
        at com.sun.javafx.collections.UnmodifiableObservableMap.callObservers(UnmodifiableObservableMap.java:65)
        at com.sun.javafx.collections.UnmodifiableObservableMap.lambda$new$30(UnmodifiableObservableMap.java:59)
        at javafx.collections.WeakMapChangeListener.onChanged(WeakMapChangeListener.java:88)
        at com.sun.javafx.collections.MapListenerHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(MapListenerHelper.java:163)
        at com.sun.javafx.collections.MapListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(MapListenerHelper.java:72)
        at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableMapWrapper.callObservers(ObservableMapWrapper.java:115)
        at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableMapWrapper.put(ObservableMapWrapper.java:173)
        at javafx.scene.media.Media.updateMetadata(Media.java:525)
        at javafx.scene.media.Media.access$200(Media.java:78)
        at javafx.scene.media.Media$_MetadataListener.lambda$onMetadata$10(Media.java:544)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: looks like the parameter passed in your onChange method is `null`, thus causing a nullpointerexception when you try to invoke methods on it

Comment: Presumably `albumPicture` is null.

Comment: albumPicture object from FXML file. If i print metadata in console, image isn't null